# How to redirect to another view from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a dropdown list that shows all games played in one round (1 week). And i'm picking that id, and it does show me all games. But now I have another button that will pick the same Id, and redirect me to my page where I will edit the scores. This doesn't work, but probably because i don't know what am I doing.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#RoundId').change(function() {
    var data = {
      roundId: $('#RoundId').val()
    };

    $.get("/Games/OfRound", data, function(result, status) {
      console.log(status);
      $('#results').html(result);
    });

    $('#editScores').click(function() {
      window.location.href = '/EditScores/Index/?=' + data.roundId;
    })
  });

  $('#RoundId').trigger("change")
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with the logic here. Firstly you're nesting the `click` handler within the `change` handler, so every time a change happens a click will be added, and another, and another...

Also you don't update the `data` object when the AJAX request completes, so the click will only ever go to the first selected `RoundId` value.

To fix this, read the `#RoundId` value when the the `click` event to redirect the page happens:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#RoundId').change(function() {
    $.get("/Games/OfRound", {
      roundId: $('#RoundId').val()
    }, function(result) {
      $('#results').html(result);
    });
  }).trigger('change');

  $('#editScores').click(function() {
    window.location.assign('/EditScores/Index/?=' + $('#RoundId').val());
  });
});
```

Note that this is assuming that `#editScores` is a static element which exists in the DOM when the page loads. If that element is instead part of the HTML appended to `#results` then you will need to replace that `click()` call with a delegated event handler:

```
$('#results').on('click', '#editScores', function() {
  window.location.assign('/EditScores/Index/?=' + $('#RoundId').val());
});
```